# Display array result in html table using array_walk or array_map

Tags: php, array-map, array-walk, array-reduce

I am working with users data inside array and I want to print user data inside html table without using foreach loop but alternative of that using array_walk()

```
<?php 
 $users=$this->db->get('user')->result();
 echo '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Edit</th></tr><tbody>';
 function myfunction($value,$key)
{
     echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td><td>Edit</td></tr>';

}
echo '</tbody></table>';
$a=array("a"=>"user1","b"=>"user2","c"=>"user3");
array_walk($a,"myfunction");

?>
```

Expected output:

```
Name     Edit

user1   edit

user2   edit

user3   edit
```

Comment: what did you get now?

Comment: @ Giacomo M not getting output  as per requirement only single line output i.e user name in single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing where you put the PHP code.
Try with this:

```
<?php
function myfunction($value, $key) {
     echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td><td>Edit</td></tr>';
}

$a = array("a" => "user1", "b" => "user2", "c" => "user3");

$users = $this->db->get('user')->result();
echo '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Edit</th></tr><tbody>';
array_walk($a, "myfunction");
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```